# Where should I place iptables update on Android at boot time?

Tags: boot, android, iptables, bootloader

I need to write specific values in the routing system using the iptables command for Android.

The overall idea is that the user can navigate **only** using the provided DNS configuration.

I've tried to invoke them inside an script through the **init.rc**, but the script is never called:

`service update_iptables /system/bin/update_iptables.sh
    start update_iptables`

When I plug the phone to the computer and execute the following sequence, it works without problems:

`adb root
adb remount
adb shell /system/bin/update_iptables.sh`

Obviously, when restarting, this configuration is lost. That's why I need to run this as part of the start boot sequence.

Any advice on where in init.rc (or any other configuration file) can I place the script?